# systemd - Giving my service multiple arguments

Tags: linux, systemd

Is it possible to give my systemd service more than one argument?

I'd like to execute a program with multiple arguments which have to be decided by the final user.

E.g: `./program arg1 arg2`

To start it a single argument app I'd need something like `systemctl start arg1@program`, where in the service definition I have `ExecStart = /usr/bin/program ℅i`.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like what you want is a config file.

Comment: I need to change it on the go. Do I strictly need a conf file?

Comment: @peperunas you don't need a conf file, see my answer which works without any extra files

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Yes you can! Define them in a file somewhere and add them to `EnvironmentFile` in your systemd Service. For example, say the contents of /etc/.progconf are:

```
ARG1=-o
ARG2=--verbose
```

And your .service file:

```
EnvironmentFile=/etc/.progconf
ExecStart=/usr/bin/prog ${ARG1} ${ARG2}
```

You can write to that file if you need to change them on the go. A service shouldn't change its options very often, maybe consider autostarting or cron if you need to achieve that.

For more examples check: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Services

Comment: Heh, quite handy, didn't think of that. I have to agree though: Service parameters don't change on a regular basis, and neither do their config files.

Comment: if the service file uses environment variables, can you say `VAR1=... VAR2=... systemctl start foobar.service` to pass the variables?

Comment: Yes, I believe you can

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, no, you can't.  There is a `PassEnvironment` directive, but it takes variables from the `systemd` process (normally PID 1), not from `systemctl`.  Environment variables from the `systemctl` process don't get propagated to the service being started.

Comment: But upstart can run multiple instances of the same service, with different parameters. For example a mail server on eth0 and another instance of said mailserver on eth1, passing the parameter to upstart and managing them as separate services. Can systemd do this?

Comment: Yes, SystemD supports such a feature using "Unit Templates". See a tutorial here: https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-template-unit-files/ . It is functionally similar to passing a single argument to the unit.

Comment: I can't agree with the remark about service parameters don't change on a regular basis. They do whatever you want them to do. Cron isn't a standard and it will most likely be fully replaced in the future by systemd timers. Systemd services have different types, they are not always daemons whose configuration shouldn't change. Why a simple timed job's configuration shouldn't change? And also - this is not about changing a configuration. This is about being able to pass more than a single parameter to an instanced service. I want to pass two arguments that are NOT shared between instances.

Comment: @Fanatique Yes, they don't have to be daemons, you could run whatever you fancy. For the most part I use services as autostarts that require the knowledge of the environment, for example starting xorg and rotating/resizing the screen to desired orientation/size on a small embedded system. Again, if you want to change them with systemctl instead of a config file, the answer that nonagon posted might suit your case, rather my "set and forget" suggestion.

Comment: It looks like the variable name needs to be enclosed in curly braces, a la `${varname}`, according to what I see in the reference (and my experience)

Answer (score 48):

I wanted to do the same thing, but without a separate file for each combination of arguments. I found that I could pass one long argument with spaces and then use systemd's environment variable space-splitting feature to separate the arguments.

I made a service with filename `argtest@.service` (*note the trailing 'at sign' which is required when a service takes arguments*).

```
[Unit]
Description=Test passing multiple arguments

[Service]
Environment="SCRIPT_ARGS=%I"
ExecStart=/tmp/test.py $SCRIPT_ARGS
```

I run this with `sudo systemctl start argtest@"arg1 arg2 arg3".service` and it passes `arg1`, `arg2` and `arg3` as separate command-line arguments to test.py.

Comment: "note the trailing ampersand": I find no ampersand in your reply. Can you edit your reply to be clearer on this point?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that!

Comment: I think the @ is only needed when you use the %I as you do. It's an instance of the service.

Comment: Agreed, I just ran into a few blog posts which omitted it. I'll clarify in my answer.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work from within another service.  I tried `Wants=argtest@"arg1 arg2".service` and only the first argument was passed.

Comment: On my debian I get `Invalid unit name "argtest@arg1 arg2.service" was escaped as "argtest@arg1\x20arg2.service" (maybe you should use systemd-escape?)`

Comment: Tried to check status of "test-systemd-params@.service" with `systemctl status test-systemd-params@.service` and it tells me `Unit name test-systemd-params@.service is neither a valid invocation ID or unit name`. :(

Comment: I had to use `${SCRIPT_ARGS}` instead of `$SCRIPT_ARGS`

Comment: > maybe you should use systemd-escape?

`sudo systemctl start $(systemd-escape --template argtest@.service "arg1 arg2 arg3")`

Comment: actually, quotes are not needed: `sudo systemctl start $(systemd-escape --template argtest@.service arg1 arg2 arg3)`

Comment: There is no reason to use `Environment`. Just specify `ExecStart=/tmp/test.py %I`.

Answer (score 7):

Easiest I have found is:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "\"/path/with spaces/to/app\" arg1 arg2 arg3 \"arg with space\""
```

Keeps it all self contained.

Having said that, I have found that at least on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I don't even need to do that, I can do this and it works fine:

```
ExecStart="/path/with spaces/to/app" arg1 arg2 arg3 "arg with space"
```

`$vars` work as arguments with this pattern as well.

Answer (score 3):

Tell your users to override the service by creating a drop-in snippet through the use of the `edit` option in [systemctl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemctl.1.html).

Firstly, start with some sane defaults. Let's assume the `ExecStart` part of your service declares the following:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=./program arg1
```

Now any user of this service can decide that they want to use a different set of arguments for running the program. They can do that by creating a drop-in snippet with:

```
systemctl edit myservice.service
```

In the new file, they simply write the following to override the `ExecStart`:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=./program arg1 arg2
```

The benefit of doing it this way is that the end result does not involve modifying the system-installed service which may conflict with some package managers.

And that's it!

Now just reload systemd (`systemctl daemon-reload`) and restart the service (`systemctl restart myservice.service`).

When the service restarts, it will always also load the user's modifications.

I hope that helps

---

#### Sources:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/659267/how-do-i-override-or-configure-systemd-services
- https://serverfault.com/questions/413397/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-systemd-service