# Stop a systemd service and clear all persistent data

Tags: linux, systemd

I have a systemd service that is making use of `DynamicUser` and `StateDirectory` in the unit file, so the service can be restarted freely without losing data. However sometimes I want to completely clean up any persistent data and start it from a blank state, can I do that with some parameters to the `systemctl stop` command?
EDIT: I'm looking for an official parameter supported by `systemctl` that will clear all persistent data, not a way to pass arguments to my script.

Comment: You can pass arguments to you stop command see [this](https://superuser.com/a/728962/742963) answer

Comment: I'm asking exactly _which arguments_ can achieve that effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual of systemd.exec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html):

> The directories specified with StateDirectory=, CacheDirectory=, LogsDirectory=, ConfigurationDirectory= are not removed when the unit is stopped.

There is no official argument supported by **systemd** that clears these directories.  You can use a script to do that.