# systemd - Giving my unit+service multiple arguments

Tags: systemd

I need a system template service with multiple (2) arguments to like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Virtualgl Manager for slurm job <jobid>
After=user@<user>.service
Requires=user@<user>.service

[Service]
User=<user>
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
Slice=user-<user>.slice
```

I need to pass in both **user** and **jobid**. The jobid is needed so every slurm job has a unique instance but I also need to pass in the  the jobs belongs to so the right user@.service is started. The goal of this service is to keep the user@.service alive for the duration of the slurm job like pam-systemd does for ssh sessions so the two can work in parallel.

I've seen [systemd - Giving my service multiple arguments](https://superuser.com/questions/728951/systemd-giving-my-service-multiple-arguments) for a similar issue but those solutions only works for the service part, not the unit.

Comment: Have you considered running the service _within_ the per-user systemd instance instead? That way it'll already have the same lifetime as the user, and will only need the job ID.

Comment: Can a per-user instance be used before user@.service is running? Is it allowed to require a system instance to start that?